# How to reduce the space between barh plot while maintaining the width

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I cannot find the proper parameter to modify in Matplotlib documentation.

I have this:

```
df.plot(kind='barh',x='Attributes',y='Counts', ax=ax1, color='#C0C0C0', width=0.3,legend= False)
```

which produces an horizontal bar plot.

I want to mantain the width = 0.3 but reduce the space between the bars.

Comment: Do you have a (fictive) data example?

Comment: Hi, did my answer help you?

Comment: you are welcome, that is great to hear !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be tweaked in the following way:

Modules & Example data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':['A','B','C'], 'y':[4,6,3]})
```

Determine position:

```
xn = [i for i, _ in enumerate(df['x'])]
```

This results in xn = [0, 1, 2].

Plot:

```
plt.barh(xn, df['y'], height=0.5)
plt.yticks(xn, df['x'])
```

The first parameter, in this case *xn*, is the one that should be adapted to change the spacing between the bars. For ex.: if you set `xn=[0, 0.8, 1.6]`, the space will reduce.